# Sampling captured point data

Tags: html, canvas

I am working on creating a web application which allows users to draw on a canvas (with mouse or touch events).

The method of capturing the path that a user draws with the mouse or a canvas is something quite close to what TLC demonstrate [in this blog post](http://tenderlovingcode.com/blog/web-apps/html5-canvas-drawing-on-ipad/).

Now what I want to do different is to:

- Store the captured coordinates drawn
  in an array (and use it for drawing)
- "Sample" the captured data i.e. only
  use some of the points for drawing
  the drawn path by the user on the
  screen

What I am currently sure about is just how I would 'sample' the array of points.

So to better explain myself, here is what I have in mind:

1. A user draws a path on the canvas (with his fingers or a mouse)
2. A total of 20 points is captured by the mouseover/touchmove events
3. If we were to draw the path drawn by using all 20 points, it will be quite jaggdy and not smooth. So what I want is to trim down the number of points from 20 to maybe 8, and use bezier curves to connect them?

Just wanted to see if anyone has implemented something similar to this. If anyone has played Flight Control on the ipad/iphone, when a user draws a path for a plane, they implement this by using some of the touchmove points and not all of them. Perhaps they use a timer?

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I was looking for turned out to be the [Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Here is an javascript implementation of the algorithm if anyone is interested - https://gist.github.com/826148